# How make button invisible based on other columns value of table - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have table in Angular. One column getting `status` and another have `button`. So based on status I want to show/hide `Send` button.

This is my code

```
<table>
<th>Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Send Button</th>
<tr *ngFor="let lst of records; let i = index" border="1">
  <td>{{lst.Name}} </td>  
  <td>{{lst.Status}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="onSelect(lst)" type="button">Send</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I am getting `lst.Status` as *Failed* I want to show button otherwise hide it. How can I do it?

Comment: Use `ngIf` or `hidden` depending on your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><button *ngIf="lst.Status === failed" (click)="onSelect(lst)" type="button">Send</button></td>
```

or you can hide through css class. If the condition is true, you set opacity: 1, if the condition fail you will set opacity: 0

```
<td><button [ngClass]="[lst.status ? 'hide' : 'show']" (click)="onSelect(lst)" type="button">Send</button></td>

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngIf` as follows. It only show the button if `lst.Status` is **Failed**. Otherwise, you won't be able to see the button. And also check if you didn't misspell your object property.

```
<td><button *ngIf="lst.Status == 'Failed'" (click)="onSelect(lst)" type="button">Send</button></td>
```